# Resize videobox for animation in slidy presentation (RMarkdown)

Tags: r, animation, knitr, gridextra, slidy

I am making a presentation that contains an animation with a grid of plots in slidy (rmarkdown). The videobox is a bit too large for the slide and I would like to reduce it. 
My presentation is similiar to this one:

````
---
title: "Adbd"
output: slidy_presentation
---

## Animation

```{r animation1,echo=FALSE,fig.align='center', fig.show='animate', aniopts='controls,width=0.1', fig.height=9, fig.width=9,fig.retina=2}
for(i in 1:2){
  library(ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)
  p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+geom_point()+xlim(1,6)+ylim(9,35)
  p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+geom_point()+xlim(1,8)+ylim(9,35)
  p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+geom_point()+xlim(1,8)+ylim(6,35)
  p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label=rownames(mtcars)))+geom_point()+xlim(1,8)+ylim(9,35)+ geom_text()

  grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, nrow=2, ncol=2) 
}
```
````

I would like to reduce the video tag's width from it's default value (864) to something like 650. I can easily do it in the .html, but, I rather change it from the .rmd document.

So far I tried:

- Adding the width parameter to aniopts, (does not have any effect)
- Playing around with fig.height and fig.width, (they change the text's size)
- Playing around with heights and widths parameters in grid.arrange, (same as before)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```css
video {
  width:  650px  !important;
  height:  auto  !important;
}
```

You can also center the video if you want

```css
video { 
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Your rmd will look like

````
---
title: "Adbd"
output: slidy_presentation
---

<style>

video {
  width:  650px  !important;
  height:  auto  !important;

  /* center the player */
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>

## Animation

```{r animation1,echo=FALSE,fig.align='center', fig.show='animate', aniopts='controls,width=0.1', fig.height=9, fig.width=9,fig.retina=2}
for(i in 1:2){
  library(ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)
  p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+geom_point()+xlim(1,6)+ylim(9,35)
  p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+geom_point()+xlim(1,8)+ylim(9,35)
  p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))+geom_point()+xlim(1,8)+ylim(6,35)
  p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label=rownames(mtcars)))+geom_point()+xlim(1,8)+ylim(9,35)+ geom_text()

  grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, nrow=2, ncol=2) 
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know I could override the width property from the css.